# Не могу найти папку .jenkins в ubuntu

Tags: linux, tomcat, jenkins

Поставил сервер tomcat по инструкции (https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/211836285-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Tomcat-9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Ubuntu-16-04), закинул jenkins.war в webapps, запустил сервер, установил jenkins. Создал пустой job, собрал. Консольный вывод пишет:

```
Building in workspace /root/.jenkins/workspace/simpleItem
Finished: SUCCESS
```

По идее должна была появиться рабочая папка джоба. Но папка root пустая, нет папки .jenkins. Как ее найти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все названия файлов и директории начинающиеся на точку скрыты (как бы для хранения пользовательских конфигов), но существуют. В менеджере файлов найди опцию или ls --all

Comment: спасибо, надо учить команды